# C# application won't run on other machines

Tags: c#, wpf, interop

Dev machine: windows 7 64 bit: runs fine

test machine windows 8.1 64 bit.

My application crashes in the InitializeComponent method and I can't figure out why. I run the exe through visual studio on the test machine and I get a "the method or operation is not implemented" exception. I've tried copying other ddl's that the test machine might not have for the exe but none have helped yet. I removed all code from my constructor except InitializeComponent. I tried running depends.exe but I can't make sense of what dll could be causing it if it is a dll. I don't have any static or dynamic resources in the xaml either. I've been at it for days, any help would be appreciated. Here's some output:

EDIT: well its not actually a not implemented exception. I hacked more code and narrowed it down to a interop type declaration that triggers a file not found exception after moving the declaration from the class body to the window loaded method.

Comment: This looks like you've auto generated a method and failed to implement it.  When you autogenerate in VS, it puts in a "NotImplemented" exception.  My guess is that you are calling that code, perhaps your versions between machines are not the same.

Comment: Also make sure you're running on .NET 4.5 on both systems.

Comment: They are exactly the same, I copy the one I just ran. I'm not aware of any code that would throw that. Why do you think it would throw that on one machine and not another?

Comment: This looks to me like you are missing a dll that is required for one of your UI components (e.g. Telerik DLLs or some such).  can you post your XAML?

Comment: I am using devexpress but I copied every devexpress dll in to the directory just to make sure and it still crashed. I just checked the test machine has .net 4.5 multi target pack and sdk.

Comment: 4.0.30319.34014 is .Net 4.5.1 on Windows 8.1; what do you have on your dev machine?

Comment: "method not implemented" is pretty clear: you've referenced an assembly containing a type which in your code expects a method that in the assembly found at run-time does not exist. No one here can fix that for you; you just need to check the exact location of the error, and possible the information in the system event log (where more detailed information for .NET exceptions can sometimes be found) to figure out which assembly is the problem. To fix it, you then provide the correct version of the assembly (i.e. the one where the method is implemented).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turned out to be a missing dll being thrown in the InitializeComponent for whatever reason. My application has a c++ library we made that uses visual c++ 2012 dlls and the application was looking for the debug version of it instead of the regular one included in the redistributable package. Tools that I used which was a life saver:

[**Process Monitor Ref Link**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx)

[**Dependz  Ref Link**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/560816/Troubleshooting-dependency-resolution-problems-usi)

Using these two applications allows you to pinpoint exactly what your application is looking for. The article is was very helpful.